# How to find the intersection of a pair of columns in pandas dataframe with pairs in any order?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below dataframe

```
col1     col2
a        b
b        a
c        d
d        c
e        d
```

Desired Output should be unique pair from two columns

```
col1    col2
a        b
c        d
e        d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to `frozenset` and then filter by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df[['col1','col2']].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    a    b
2    c    d
4    e    d
```

Or you can sorting values by `np.sort` and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['col1','col2']]), columns=['col1','col2']).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    a    b
2    c    d
4    d    e
```